# @ : = operators / keywords in mysql

Tags: mysql, operator-keyword

I have seen a row like this in the SELECT part of a mysql query:

```
@acc:=`account`.`accountid` AS `accountid`
```

In other parts of the query they use it like:

```
WHERE `accountid`=@acc
```

What does @acc:= mean?

Comment: they are using variable in query.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-user-variables.html